# Deploy .zip archive (python code) to Azure Function using TerraForm

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions

I am having issues with uploading Python code to a Function App, in the sense that the function-app is created, but the code is not uploaded in the "Function" section, but rather in the "AppFiles" (there is no function in "Functions" in Azure Portal).

Here is my TerraForm code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "archive_file" "function_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger"
  output_path = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger.zip"
  depends_on = [null_resource.pip]
}

resource "null_resource" "pip" {
  triggers = {
    requirements_md5 = "${filemd5("../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger/requirements.txt")}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {    
    command = "pip install --target='.python_packages/lib/site-packages' -r requirements.txt"
    working_dir = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger"
  }
}

#Uploading to the blob container
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "storage_blob_function" {
  name                   = "my-function.zip"
  storage_account_name   = "***"
  storage_container_name = "***"
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger.zip"
}

# Create Azure App Service Plan using Consumption pricing
resource azurerm_service_plan "app_service_plan" {
  name                   = "app_service_plan"
  location               = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name    = "***"
  os_type                = "Linux"
  sku_name               = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "blurring_fn_app" {
  name                = "calinfntest-app-terraform"
  location            = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name = "***"


  storage_account_name       = "***"
  storage_account_access_key = "***"
  app_service_plan_id =  azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan.id

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = azurerm_storage_blob.storage_blob_function.url
  }
  site_config {}
}
```

Observations:

The function-app is successfully created, the pip packages are successfully installed inside the `.zip` package that is uploaded on a blob container within a storage account (I double-checked this step, even in the logs of TerraForm) and the `.zip` is successfully uploaded to the blob container specified in `azurerm_function_app` resource.

The `terraform apply` runs successfully, but when I open the Azure Portal and go the the function app, there is no actual function deployed (no functions available).

However, I can I can see my code appearing in "AppFiles" section as denoted below, but not in the Function section.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here :

```
data "archive_file" "function_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger"
  output_path = "../${path.module}/blob_storage_trigger.zip"
  depends_on = [null_resource.pip]
}
```

The `.zip` would need an additional, upper-level folder in order to properly create a nested folder so that the application is correctly deployed.

So the `source_dir` needs to be like `"../${path.module}/upper_level_folder_name"`, which in essence contains the "blob_storage_trigger" folder.

Eventually, the structure of the deployment must look like:

```
.zip
   -function_1
           -.zipped_code_for_function_1

   -function_2
           -.zipped_code_for_function_2
```

My problem was that in `.zip` I only put `.zipped_code_for_function_1`.

Consequently, the problem is solved by respecting the structure from above.